# uint8_t VS uint32_t different behaviour

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am currently working on project where I need to use uint8_t. I have found one problem, could someone explain to me why this happens ?

```
//using DIGIT_T = std::uint8_t;
using DIGIT_T = std::uint32_t;
std::uint8_t bits = 1;
DIGIT_T test1 = ~(DIGIT_T)0;
std::cout << std::hex << (std::uint64_t)test1 << std::endl;
DIGIT_T test2 = ((~(DIGIT_T)0) >> bits);
std::cout << std::hex << (std::uint64_t)test2 << std::endl;
```

in this case the output is as expected

```
ffffffff
7fffffff
```

but when I uncomment the first line and I use uint8_t the output is

```
ff
ff
```

This behaviour is causing me troubles.

Thank you for your help.

Marek

Comment: `~(DIGIT_T)0` is equivalent to `~(int)(DIGIT_T)0`, or just `~0`. According to the rules of both C and C++, arguments of arithmetic and bitwise operators are subject to integral promotions. See [Integral promotion paragraph](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

Comment: Rules of integral promotion mean that `~(DIGIT_T)0` is equivalent to `~(int)0` if `DIGIT_T` supports a smaller range than an `int`.

Comment: the posted code is `C++` not `C`  please remove the `c` tag

Comment: well, the value being output is either (per posted code) a 32bit value or (with the first `#define` uncommented) a 8 bit value.   So naturally the resulting outputs are either 32 bit or 8 bit.

Comment: @user3629249 I had the problem in C code, this was just a fast snippet of code to present the problem :)

Comment: @user3411282,  C and C++ are two different languages.  When asking about C code, the posted code needs to be in C.   The posted code, for a C problem is about as useful as if it were posted in ADA or LISP or BASIC.

Comment: @user3411282, you're stretching it a bit too thin. Though C and C++ are two different languages, they still do share a lot of common features. The issue in question *is* one of these common features. It is quite a mechanical task to rewrite the code into pure C. Thus, your claim that it '*is about as useful as if it were posted in ADA or LISP or BASIC*' is untrue.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already explained in details, this is caused by integer promotion.  This should do the trick:

```
DIGIT_T test2 = ((DIGIT_T)(~(DIGIT_T)0) >> bits);
```

which can of course be shortened to:

```
DIGIT_T test2 = (DIGIT_T)~0 >> bits;
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/PS8jHE)